# Update seq based on criteria - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
id  element_id  element_value   lx_seq  line_num
59  A301-01     Test            1       25
59  A301-01     Test            1       26
59  K301-01     Test            1       27
59  K301-01                     1       28
59  K302-01     18105678982800  1       28
59  K304-01     TOPS            1       28
59  K305-01     7               1       28
59  K306-01     888P            1       28

60  K301-01     Test            1       27
60  K301-01                     1       28
60  K302-01     18105678982800  1       28
60  K304-01     TOPS            1       28
60  K305-01     7               1       28
60  K306-01     888P            1       28

61  K301-01     Test            1       27
61  K301-01                     1       27

62  K301-01     Test            1       27
62  K301-01                     1       28
62  K301-01     18105678982800  1       29
62  K304-01     TOPS            1       29
62  K305-01     7               1       29
62  K306-01     888P            1       29
```

This is the output table:

table2

```
id  element_id  element_value   lx_seq  line_num
59  A101-01     Test            1       25
59  A101-01     Test            1       26
59  K301-01     Test            1       27
59  K301-01                     2       28
59  K302-01     18105678982800  2       28
59  K304-01     TOPS            2       28
59  K305-01     7               2       28
59  K306-01     888P            2       28

60  K301-01     Test            1       27
60  K301-01                     2       28
60  K302-01     18105678982800  2       28
60  K304-01     TOPS            2       28
60  K305-01     7               2       28
60  K306-01     888P            2       28

61  K301-01     Test            1       27
61  K301-01                     1       27

62  K301-01     Test            1       27
62  K301-01                     2       28
62  K301-01     18105678982800  3       29
62  K304-01     TOPS            3       29
62  K305-01     7               3       29
62  K306-01     888P            3       29
```

I need to update lx_seq if and only if in 1 id, we have multiple K3 + line_num combination. It should not work for any other elements like A1.

How can I increase lx_seq based on the above condition in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 0):

you need `dense_rank()` function for `lx_seq` column as below

`dense_rank() over (partition by id order by line_num) as lx_seq`,

and it's not to hold an already calculated column within a column, that violates the normalization rule for database.

Comment: Where does it check for K3?

Comment: @dang hm, you asked also for K3, but I think you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like following using dense_rank

```
--first select all not K3 rows and keep lx_seq same    
SELECT id, element_id, element_value, lx_seq, line_num 
from table1 where element_id not like 'K3%'
UNION ALL
--select K3 rows and based on id and line_num generate rank
SELECT id, element_id, element_value, 
dense_rank() over (partition by id, line_num order by line_num) lx_seq, 
line_num 
from table1 where element_id  like 'K3%'
```

Example Update statement:

```
MERGE INTO table1 A USING
(
    SELECT id, element_id, element_value, 
    dense_rank() over (partition by id, line_num order by line_num) lx_seq, 
    line_num 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE element_id  LIKE 'K3%'
) B 
ON (A.id = B.id AND A.line_num = B.line_num AND A.element_id = B.element_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET A.lx_seq = B.lx_seq;
```

Comment: @dang, you can use the SQL and write your own update statement. I added an example how to use that, verify your join conditions before you execute it.

Comment: dense_rank() over (partition by id, line_num order by line_num) lx_seq, -- doesn't seem to work. It is keeping lx_seq to be same.

Comment: It should just be partition by id order by line_num